# Почему NameError, когда указан global?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fy():
    global b
    b = 2
print(b) #NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Что не так?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 4):

`global` создает переменную в глобальной области видимости.
В своем коде вы только объявили функцию, но переменная `b` будет создана только после её вызова.

```
def func():
    global b
    b = 2

func()
print(b)  # 2
```

Comment: Точнее говоря global ничего не создает. Эта директива говорит интерпретатору в какой области видимости ему искать переменную с таким именем. Без явного присвоения переменная не будет создана.

Comment: Да, все так. 2 строчки вместе `global b; b=2` создают переменную в глобальной области видимости. Это я позволил себе вольность в высказываниях, когда торопился ответить на вопрос.